# Merge C# source files into one

Tags: c#, merge

I am participating in a programming competition, The competition uses a website where you just upload your source file and than it tests it, The problem is that I have multiple C# Source files. Is there a software or website which allows me to merge multiple C# source files into one?

I would happily ZIP the files but the website does not support uploading ZIP files with the sources inside...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and found that a solution as proposed by i486 is actually doable.

You can merge all cs files into one, but you have to take care of usings.

To put it simply all code **needs** to be inside a namespace. Yes, even the usings, especially those, else you're going to have compiler errors.

To make that even easier you could even StyleCop with the rule ["SA1200: Using Directives Must Be Placed Correctly"](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1200.md) to enforce this.

Also to clarify, you don't need a namespace per file, it is perfectly acceptable to have the same namespace multiple times in a file.

Answer (score 0):

From Command Prompt, go to folder with C# files and run this:

```
for %a in (*.cs) do type %a >>all.txt
```

Then rename `all.txt` to `all.cs`

Comment: That won't work you can't put a `using` statement to include a namespace halfway though a file.